# NPM Install error on Ubuntu 16.04 but not Windows 10

Tags: angular, ubuntu, npm

I'm getting an error running npm install on my project in Ubuntu 16.04

I can't figure out if this is a problem with npm, or execsync, or maybe angular? It installs and builds fine in Windows 10, which is also confusing me. I'm not able to launch my MEAN stack website because I can't get past these errors.

npm -v: 3.5.2

Here is the error.

```
> execSync@1.0.2 install /home/tony/web/sa_website/node_modules/execSync
> node install.js

sh: 1: node: not found
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.2
npm WARN @angular/core@2.0.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/http@2.0.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.0.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm ERR! Linux 4.8.0-58-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! execSync@1.0.2 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the execSync@1.0.2 install script 'node install.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the execSync package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs execSync
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls execSync
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/tony/web/sa_website/npm-debug.log
```

And the error seen at the end of npm-debug.log

```
640 warn optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
641 warn notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.2
642 warn @angular/core@2.0.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
643 warn @angular/http@2.0.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
644 warn @angular/router@3.0.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
645 verbose stack Error: execSync@1.0.2 install: `node install.js`
645 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
645 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:17:16)
645 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
645 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
645 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:821:16)
645 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
646 verbose pkgid execSync@1.0.2
647 verbose cwd /home/tony/web/sa_website
648 error Linux 4.8.0-58-generic
649 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
650 error node v4.2.6
651 error npm  v3.5.2
652 error file sh
653 error code ELIFECYCLE
654 error errno ENOENT
655 error syscall spawn
656 error execSync@1.0.2 install: `node install.js`
656 error spawn ENOENT
657 error Failed at the execSync@1.0.2 install script 'node install.js'.
657 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
657 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the execSync package,
657 error not with npm itself.
657 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
657 error     node install.js
657 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
657 error     npm bugs execSync
657 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
657 error     npm owner ls execSync
657 error There is likely additional logging output above.
658 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

And here is package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular2-nodejs",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "build": "del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch",
    "build:prod": "del-cli public/js/app && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail && del-cli 'public/js/app/**/*.js' 'public/js/app/**/*.js.map' '!public/js/app/bundle.js' '!public/js/app/*.chunk.js' 'assets/app/**/*.ngfactory.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.shim.ts'",
    "ngc" : "ngc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.4",
    "hbs": "~4.0.0",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.34",
    "@types/node": "6.0.45",
    "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.79.0",
    "del-cli": "^0.2.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "nodemailer": "^4.0.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "typescript": "2.0.3",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.21",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Per the angular docs: *Verify that you are running at least node `6.9.x` and npm `3.x.x` by running `node -v` and `npm -v` in a terminal/console window. Older versions produce errors, but newer versions are fine.* You are running node `v4.2.6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by R. Richards, your node version is not supported by angular, just update node with
`sudo npm install -g n
sudo n latest`

 and then just run 
`npm install -g npm` to upgrade npm